# What is this cable?

Tags: cable

I found this USB to something connector. The something part has three pin connectors, and two latches on the sides. It displays a dotted rhombus on top of it, with 5 dots over the diagonals. [image: top view[1]]
[image: front view]

Comment: Could downvoters please give a reason? I've seen questions analogous to this one, with noone complaining.

Comment: Well the dots look like Fitbit's logo, could be a Fitbit device?  Not sure which one however.

Comment: "Guess the connector/thing/widget" questions are generally disliked: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not/7649#7648

Comment: "These questions contribute nothing to SU, and cost us time to answer (however small), and most importantly do not help future visitors."


This really disappoints me. What about the simple reward of helping one another?

Comment: It's more the fact that we might have a thousand of those questions and answers and they're all effectively useless to each other because we have no way to find them to mark them as duplicates of each other. No one question is usefully searchable to point the next person who asks an identical question at.

Comment: Heck, even a google image search is essentially useless because every picture is so damn similar to every other picture of a random cable with random connectors on it: https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitS_1cntbcZs7sk8sako-s3_1DSqDNEGyu0ylnocbFnSX0KThAJrQ9ycuGPgI1OFuEODB2D9wqtkSXL1KLISapvcB_1oPGNyvDGKapYMhCE_11yMRTQDbtWYG8f6WyqWgkxAw7Or9TNDkInZo07kHkxfnDQXp6UUdn8epoypc0rH2aGDv7fmzhSApPOznsr-7dTKP1R5k_1jHojfWkm_1723_1lAtjTGBMuM_1BOdGK5GMljl8FQFIHGXTDqqtwd4KghjSjSNwuR8AMsq4VvnPReVoEVqJccBFNdXpQjYkqrPSU8hV5U21_1c2UaUts7qUPFAue3WbYrOTgM&gws_rd=cr&ei=33qUWbLVBeGagAbn05OYAw

Comment: I understand that issue, but that still doesn't convince me of such a question being something negative. Only less positive, but still useful for the one asking.

Comment: Yup, and I'm very happy that you answered and my unresting soul can finally settle :)

Comment: I guess I'm just generally unhappy with stackexchange's harsh deprecating policies. But then again, I have no experience whatsoever as a moderator.

Comment: I guess the way to think about it would be: what would *you* search for when googling such a problem? Would you rather click through dozens of “What is this cable?” questions on various Q&A sites and forums, or would you rather want to find a comprehensive “How do I identify a cable?” post? It's the latter we want to see more of.

Comment: Side note: this rhombus looks like a square. Any square is a rhombus, so you're technically right. But I suppose if the sides were vertical and horizontal, you would call the shape "square" without even considering calling it "rhombus". Here you perceive one of the diagonals as vertical and you say "rhombus", possibly without considering "square". Note even "vertical" and "horizontal" in this case are defined by some frame of reference that is in itself *arbitrary* (you can reorient the cable freely). This is a nice example of how choosing the reference frame affects our perception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a [Fitbit FB156RCC Charge HR Charging Cable.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0178Z1KGC)

[image]
<sub>(source: [bing.net](https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.gnCIapfVE_Ljr96s75j0EgEsEs&pid=15.1))</sub>

Specifications: [Fitbit Charge HR](https://www.fitbit.com/global/us/products#specs)

Comment: It could also go to any other Fitbit device that uses a similar charging cable.  Since I don't know which Fitbit devices you actually have I cannot say with a 100% certainty that the only device that used this specific charging cable was the `Fitbit Charge HR`